# mod rewrite convert to lowercase and repace + with -

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a simple news site that gets news from Rss feeds. Currently the Urls are something like this:

http://domain.com/news/This+and+That+Happened+There/

I would simply like to change this to

http://domain.com/news/this-and-that-happened-there/
(looks more clean)
Your help will be appreciated

Comment: "Change" where exactly? In the feeds? What does your .htaccess look like at the moment?

Comment: @Pekka I want my .htaccess to rewrite the links to the news pages
my .htaccess -->
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

Comment: Why do you need .htaccess to do that - would it not be much easier to make your server-side script accept `-` instead of `+`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I doubt it's possible in your case. Based on what you're saying, it's the `This+and+That+Happened+There` part that is the unique ID of the news item and that would mean that it has to remain unchanged in order for it to work on the website (be recognised on the backend/database).

If, on the other hand, you have some other ID in the url. Say `http://domain.com/news/This+and+That+Happened+There/123/` where `123` is the ID, then it should be doable, as whatever's before that shouldn't matter. All you'd need is to have your CMS (or whatever backend you're using) to have the urls formatted that way.

You did add `seo` tag to this question, so I understand that's what you want improve. I'd say in this case it won't matter (but I'm not expert in that field).